# What is the relation between time taken to detect an object in an image and training an image?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I have an ML model that takes **`X`** seconds to detect an object in an image on which it is trained. Does that mean it took at least **`X`** or **`X+Y`** seconds during training per image? **Can you provide a detailed insight?**

For instance, Assume the training speed of SSD512 model is 30 images per second on a hardware platform, Does this imply that I will be able to achieve the inference speed of at least (if not more) than 30 images per second?

The question is not confined to neural network models. A generic insight is appreciated. I am dealing with Cascade Classifiers in my case. I am loading a cascade.xml trained model to detect an object. I want to know the relation between the time taken to train an image and the time taken to detect an object after loading the trained model.

Answer (score 2):

Because unstated, I assume here you mean neural network ML model.
The training process could be seen as two steps: running the network to detect the object and updating the weights to minimize the loss function.

- Running the network: while training, the backpropagation part you essentially run the network as if you are detecting the object using the current network weights, which take X time as you stated. It should take the same as when used after the training, for example on the test dataset (to make things simple I am ignoring the mini-batch learning usually used, which might change things).
- Updating the weights: this part in the training is done by the completing the backpropagation algorithm which tells you how changing the weights will affect your detection performance (i.e. lower the loss function for the current image) then usually a stochastic gradient descent iteration is done, which updates the weights. This is the Y you stated, which in fact could be bigger than X.

These two parts are done for every image (more commonly, for every mini-batch) in the training process.

UPDATE: You said in your response that you are looking for an answer for a generic algorithm. It is an interesting question! When looking on the training task, you always need to learn some kind of weights W that is the outcome of the training process and is the essence of what was learned. The update needs to make the learned function better, which basically sounds harder than simply running the function. I really don't know of any algorithm (certainly not the commonly used ones) that would take less training time than running time per image, but it might be theoretically possible.